# Any option to move a div to the left side within a container using Onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working on JavaScript and jQuery, and my question is related to `div`s in an HTML page. Given that I am using 2 `div`s in an HTML page, is there any option to reduce the size of one `div` and expand the size of another using `onclick` event. I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/5/) which has a `div` overlapping the other div when clicked.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
  var expanded = false;
  $('#sidebar').click(function() {
    if (!expanded) {
      $(this).animate({'left' : '70px'}, {duration : 400});
      expanded = true;
    }
    else {
      $(this).animate({'left' : '565px'}, {duration: 400});
      expanded = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: in jsfiddle, You have given, you are using '.' instead of '#' to select sidebar in style.

Comment: @Jaydev : i have also used same name for the  id as sidebar for the the div.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to do slidedown and slideup in onclick event

```
$(function()
  {
      var expanded = false;
      $('#flip').click(function(){
          $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
      });
  })
```

Take a look at the working sample at [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-make-the-div-slidedown-and-slideup-in-onclick-event-2/)

Answer (score 0):

try this one, http://jsfiddle.net/markipe/3DpfJ/45/

```
    $(function(){
      var expanded = false;
      $('#sidebar').click(function(){
          if (!expanded)
          {
              $('#sidebar').animate({width:'69%'}, 400);
              $('#steam').animate({width:'29%'}, 400);
              expanded = true;
          }
          else
          {
              $('#sidebar').animate({width:'29%'}, 400);
              $('#steam').animate({width:'69%'}, 400);
              expanded = false;
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks markipe. is there any option to make the same set of things in a way like when we click the div which is there in the top, it must pop down and the div which is expanded must shrink to its left .

Comment: I cannot really understand what you meant but you can play with it, using "animate". Refer to this http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: great markipe. my need is like this 
   |
<--V .  so when i click the top button the thing which is below the button  must shrink to left. and same viceversa. i think you can get an idea from a arrow representation in this comment. in other words any option to make the div slidedown and slideup in onclick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want vice versa, pls check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/3DpfJ/47/

```
  $('#sidebar').click(function(){
      $(this).animate({width:'100px'}, 400);
      $('#steam').animate({width:'500px'}, 400);
  });
  $('#steam').click(function(){
      $(this).animate({width:'100px'}, 400);
      $('#sidebar').animate({width:'500px'}, 400);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

in below demo we can add n number of div children "mainContainer" div Please check DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/mahesh2524/RqJt7/6/

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<div id="steam"></div>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar"></div>    
<div id="sidebar2" class="sidebar"></div>
```